# Safari Extension: Passing variable from active tab to toolbar

Tags: javascript, variables, safari-extension

I'm fairly new to creating Safari Extensions and am looking for some advice regarding passing a variable from the active tab to the Extension's toolbar.

I am using a framework called jsPDF that creates PDFs using Javascript. At the moment, I have a simple toolbar with a button to click that will generate a PDF for a customer's name and product purchased, creating a simple packing slip. This is working fine, it just has some placeholder text.

The customer's name and product purchased is within the main page of a web-based system (plain text within a DIV called #name and #product). What I'd like to do is when the button is pressed, it gets the name and product purchased from the respective DIV (#name and #product) and the text is defined as a variable within the toolbar. The PDF generator works with just a standard variable so I need more help about how exactly to get the toolbar to obtain the name and product via a proxy script.

If anyone could shed any light on how to do this - I've been reading the Extension Developer Guide which has been very useful but I just can't figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

From the injected script:

```
safari.self.tab.dispatchMessage("messageName", { messageObject });
```

From the toolbar:

```
safari.self.browserWindow.addEventListener("message", messageHandler, false);
function messageHandler(event)
{
    if (event.name === "messageName")
        doStuffHereWithMessageObject();
}
```